# duktape modSearch. Native implementation in C

Tags: javascript, duktape

I have trying to implement a native-C duktape modSearch and I am stuck. I  read DUKtape documentation and looked at https://github.com/svaarala/duktape/issues/194 but still I am not able to make it work.

I created a simple test that I am using the implement modSearch, below are the details:

- I have a simple javascript that implements a square function. I am calling it testR.js:

  exports.area = function(r){
      return r*r;
  };

-A file that uses above simple function is called usetestR.js:

```
function main(){
// const square = require('./testR.js');   --> use this line for nodeJS
const square = require('testR.js');
var ts = square.area(8);

    // console.log(ts); -> used this line for nodeJS 
    print(ts);
}

main();
```

Now with duktape, I started implemented the function modSearch in C as Follows:

```
/* Declaration */
void modSearch_register(duk_context *ctx) {
    duk_get_global_string(ctx, "Duktape");
    duk_push_c_function(ctx, mod_search, 4 /*nargs*/);
    duk_put_prop_string(ctx, -2, "modSearch");
    duk_pop(ctx);
}
```

mod_search

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "duktape.h"

duk_ret_t mod_search(duk_context *ctx) {
/* Nargs was given as 4 and we get the following stack arguments:
 *   index 0: id
 *   index 1: require
 *   index 2: exports
 *   index 3: module
 */

 int     rc;

// Get ID
char *id        = duk_require_string(ctx, 0);

printf("ID => %s \n", id);
rc = strcmp(id, "testR.js");
if(rc == 0)
{
    printf("Module found, loading... \n");

    // Read File
    duk_push_object(ctx);
    duk_put_global_string(ctx, "exports");
    if(duk_peval_file(ctx,"testR.js" )!= 0)
        printf("Problem !!! \n");
    else{
        printf("Pass !!! \n");
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

When I run the code this is what I have:

```
ID => testR.js 
Module found, loading... 
Pass !!! 
TypeError: undefined not callable
    duk_js_call.c:776
    main usetestR.js:3
    global usetestR.js:8 preventsyield
error in executing file usetestR.js
```

Can you help me and point where is the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I figured it out ...
Perhaps the example can help others in the future :)

Below is the modSearch that works

```
duk_ret_t mod_search(duk_context *ctx) {
    /* Nargs was given as 4 and we get the following stack arguments:
     *   index 0: id
     *   index 1: require
     *   index 2: exports
     *   index 3: module
     */
char *src = NULL;
FILE *f   = NULL;
const char *filename = "/home/testR.js";

int  rc, len;

// Pull Arguments
char *id        = duk_require_string(ctx, 0);

printf("ID => %s \n", id);

rc = strcmp(id, "testR.js");
if(rc == 0)
{
    printf("Module found, loading... \n");
    // Read File and calculate its size (as DUKtape examples)
    f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    len = (int) ftell(f);

    // Rewind
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

    src = malloc(len);
    fread(src, 1, len,f);
    fclose(f);
    duk_push_lstring(ctx, src, len);
    free(src);
    return 1;
  }

    // Error
    return -1;
}
```

Running the program, it shows

```
ID => testR.js 
Module found, loading... 
64
```

With the basics understood, it would be possible to do a more sophisticated ways to implement modSearch.